# change the way the form is submitted without using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that is used for search on a website.

```
<form method="get" action="example.com/search">
<input type="text" name="search"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Lets say that I searched for "stack" when submitting I want the user to get redirected to `example.com/search:stack`
right now when submitting user gets redirected to : `example.com/search?search=stack`

How can I achieve that and allow it on devices that does not support javascript!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set up your search page to redirect your users from `/search?search=stack` to `/search:stack`.

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
    $search = $_GET['search'];
    header('Location: /search:'.$search);
}
else
    // no query handling
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Submitting a form in the way you describe, i.e. with the GET method, encodes the content of the form as a query string, which has this form:

```
?search=stack
```

See section 4.10.22 of the [HTML5 Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#form-submission-2) or section 17.13.3 of the [HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-data-set).

**Correction**: I'm sorry, I did not understand your question correctly. You indeed cannot change how the form is submitted, but you can redirect afterwards as you suggest.
Álvaro Martínez suggests a good way to accomplish that in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27736821/4402557).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [Url rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) to do that.
[URL Rewriting for Beginners](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)